# Voting emails from Outlook with Microsoft Exchange not accessible via IMAP on Thunderbird

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, exchange, imap

My company uses Microsoft Outlook for email and most of the users are on Windows using Outlook. I use Linux and so can't use Outlook.

I am using Thunderbird to access email via IMAP and am not getting the *voting buttons* that my colleagues are sending for various stuff. Is there any way I can read the voting options sent, and spoof a response by sending a manually written message (in a particular syntax maybe)?

Comment: If your company is using Exchange, why don't you use Outlook Web App/Access?

Comment: I don't see the voting buttons even in the OWA-light, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I am not even sure if it is in the full version of OWA, as I have never used the voting feature.  OWA is still much better than having to resort to using IMAP, however.  If you could sort out a terminal server user account, you could always use Outlook through RDP.

Comment: @paradroid, yes that is a solution, but neither is it feasible in my case nor is it as comfortable as a local mail client :)

Answer (score 2):

I found there is a format. Just change the header of the response for your option.

For example

> Would you come to the meeting?

You reply to that voting email with `Yes: Would you come to the meeting?` beside `Re: Would you come to the meeting?`.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I am not using tbird currently (have moved on to using gmail as a POP client), but will check this out when I can. Good to know.

Comment: Be aware that the sender can adjust the default text (e.g. Yes) to other options.  For example if someone sent out a request for who ordered a lunch from a given vendor the vote response text may have been changed to "Ordered Lunch" and instead of the reply being "Yes: ..." it would be "Ordered Lunch: ...".  If you poke around after MIME/Base64 decoding in the message you can find what the text is.